# GTA V and the GTA V iFruit app

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-ifruit

I got the iFruit app for GTA V and I was wondering, for the Chop training on the app to carry over to the game, do you have to be connected to the internet on your console or will it also take affect without an internet connection?

Also will the car modifications work without an internet connection or do you need a connection to get the message from Los Angeles Customs?

Basically what I'm asking is will the modifications you make on your car and the training done on Chop from the app take affect on offline single player on GTA V without having an internet connection or gold membership?

Answer (score 1):

No. Nothing will be able to be sent to your Xbox if it is not connected to the internet. So offline singleplayer will not be affected.